# How to create react-select dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I would like to create a react-select dropdown but I have no clue how to bind options with my list object. Error message: "TypeError: options.reduce is not a function..." Below is my code:

*App.js*

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'; 
import myDropdown from './myDropdown'; 

class App extends Component{ 
   state={valeu:''}; 
   onChange=(event)=>{ //do something } 
   render(){ 
      return( 
         <div><myDropdown onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.value} /</div> 
      ) 
   } 
}
```

*myDropdown.js*

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Select from 'react-select';

class myDropdown extends Component{
    state={List:{value:'',label:''} };      
    //call api to get data
    getLists= ()=>{
        axios.get('myapiurl')
        .then(response=>{
           this.setState(prevState => ({
            List: {                   // object that we want to update
                ...prevState.List,    // keep all other key-value pairs
                value: prevState.List.SUBJECT,
                label: prevState.List.CATEGORY     
            }
        }))

          });  

        };
    componentDidMount(){

         this.getLists();

      }
//render dropdown 
    render(){


        return(
            <Select value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChange} options={this.state.List} />


        );
    }

 }


  export default myDropdown;
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at this section in the documentation: https://react-select.com/async